# Linear regression for each category in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I have a super simple dataset, with 3 columns only
first column is id, it's a 6 digit number that's repeated
second column is day, it's days within a 14 day period (some days are missing)
third column is views, it's the number of views collected from a certain day from a certain id.

I was wondering if there's a way to do regression for each of the id's?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a more specific question which answer is not so obvious, otherwise your question will be downgraded!

Comment: What did you tried so far? Give more information (data and code) in your question. And look at the example of `by()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick toy example applying lapply to the iris dataset and estimating different regressions for each level of a factor variable.

```
results <- lapply(levels(iris$Species), function(id)
                   lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris[iris$Species == id, ]))
names(results) <- levels(iris$Species)
summary(results[["virginica"]])
```

The by approach recommended above is more concise

```
results2 <- by(iris, iris$Species,
   function(x) lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = x))
summary(results2[["virginica"]])
```